# typescript generic type not assignable for default

Tags: typescript

The following code:

```
function foo<T>(create: T & ((...args: any[]) => any) = () => { return { type: 'abc' }; })
{ ... }
```

Results with this error:

> Type `() => { type: string; }` is not assignable to type `T`

However, this works fine:

```
function foo<T>(create: T & ((...args: any[]) => any)) { ... }

foo(() => { return { type: "ABC" }; });
```

In the latter case, `() => { type: string; }` is assigned to `T`

Why is that?

It is on TypeScript nightly build 1.9.0-dev.20160622

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense that it fails when you set the default value but doesn't when you call the function with a value.

In the function definition, the `T` is not known, and so the type `T & ((...args: any[]) => any)` is also unknown.
[Intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types):

> An intersection type, Person & Serializable & Loggable, for example,
>   is a Person and Serializable and Loggable. That means an object of
>   this type will have all members of all three types.

But with your example, what does it mean to a `T`?

When you actually call the function and pass a value then the compiler can try and figure out what this `T` is, and so it doesn't fail and infer that `T` is `() => { type: string; }`.

The same will happen with:

```
function fn<T>(a: T & string = "str") { // fails
    return null;
}

fn2("str"); // doesn't fail
```

However, if you'll use a [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) then it will not fail:

```
function fn<T>(a: T | string = "str") {
    return null;
}
```

Because "str" is a string and so what `T` is, isn't relevant.

---

#### Edit

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but I get the feeling that using intersection types isn't the right thing for you.

If I do understand you, then this is a better solution:

```
type MyCallback = (...args: any[]) => any;
let defaultFn: MyCallback = () => { return { type: 'abc' }; };

function doSomething<T extends MyCallback>(fn: T = defaultFn as T) {
    ...
}
```

You can use an interface instead of the `type`:

```
interface MyCallback {
    (...args: any[]): any;
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F*interface%20MyCallback%20%7B%0A%09(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20any%3B%0A%7D*%2F%0A%0Atype%20MyCallback%20%3D%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20any%3B%0Alet%20defaultFn%3A%20MyCallback%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20return%20%7B%20type%3A%20'abc'%20%7D%3B%20%7D%3B%0A%0Afunction%20doSomething%3CT%20extends%20MyCallback%3E(fn%3A%20T%20%3D%20defaultFn%20as%20T)%20%7B%0A%09...%0A%7D))

Comment: Great answer. Does it mean `T` in `T & ((...args: any[]) => any)` just enforces the calling argument is a function that complies with `((...args: any[]) => any)`. And since it is inferred as `T`, allows the type of the `create` parameter to be `T` (i.e. `() => { type: string; }` in the example)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Intersection types mean that `A & B` is expected to be BOTH an `A` and a `B`.

Comment: Yes, and since `A` is `<T>` in this case, it can be anything (inferred) as long as `A & B` is satisfied. That means, this is basically a trick to infer the type of `create` parameter.

Comment: Well, it can be "anything", but it's not as easy to satisfy it (because of the `& B`) as it is to satisfy `T | B`.  Are you sure you want to use intersection types and not union types?

Comment: Yup. Positive on that. It is a trick to infer type of `create`. Inside that function, I return `{ create: create as T, ... }` So the return value of that function have the right type of `create` when use. Intersection won't work in this case. :)  Was wondering why the default value can't infer `T` as in the call site.

Comment: So maybe the question is shouldn't the default value evaluation to be treated as call site instead of declaration site.

Comment: Check my revised answer